# I need a simple character counter in my React Native with Expo

Tags: react-native

I had build a simple character counter with React Native under the Expo Frame .
However ,I had met a issue ,seems I can't get the length of the input text ..
I have attached my code ,could you please help me to take a lool ?

Thank you so much!!

```
   import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import AppTextInput from '../components/AppTextInput';
import AppFormFlied from './../components/AppFormFlied';
import AppButton from './../components/AppButton';

function CommentsHome(props) {
    const [value,setValue] = useState("");
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppTextInput icon='feather'
         placeholder="Left something.." 
         maxLength={100} 
         multiline={true}
         onChangeText={(text)=>setValue({text})}
         />
         <Text>Character Left ：{value.length === null ? 0 : value.length}/100</Text>
        <AppButton title="Submit"/>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container  : {
        width  : "100%",
        justifyContent : "center",
        alignItems : 'center',
        flexDirection : 'column',
    }
})
export default CommentsHome;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useless brackets in this context

Change

```
onChangeText={(text)=>setValue({text})}
```

By

```
onChangeText={(text)=>setValue(text)}
```

And don't need to check if the length is null because you init the value at "" so length start at 0

Comment: Hey BloodyMonkey ,thank you soooo much !!